# Can't get out of a mission

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm stuck in the mission [Tending the Flames](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tending_the_Flames). First of all, the ghost doesn't have the scroll and no matter what I do, reload, shout, use fire, nothing happens. I can't get the scroll. I also went down a well during the mission and have no way back up and with no previous saves as I cleared all but the last few, is it true I'm just officially stuck in this mission with no way out?

Comment: Is this PC or Console?

Comment: If you are on PC, you could use some console commands to get out of this predicament.

Comment: Well if you already tried fire with no success....

Comment: [This person](http://www.gameskyrim.com/tending-the-flames-game-breaking-glitch-t208113.html) has seen some success by just blasting the verse out of where it had glitched into the floor.

Answer (score 4):

Usually people note their troubles and solutions in [the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tending_the_Flames). See the [bugs section](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tending_the_Flames#Bugs) down the bottom. There's also [this wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tending_the_Flames), but unless you're on a PC it may be hard to take advantage of the useful [console toolset](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).

If you are on pc you can teleport (out of the well) using `moveto` or `movetoqt`, and as for finishing the quest you can outright progress (cheat) with `setstage` or simply add the missing scroll to your inventory with `additem` and hopefully progress the quest normally.

Definitely read up on the commands and save before using them if you're new to the console.

---

The ID for [King Olaf's Verse](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:King_Olaf%27s_Verse) is `000AE324` if you are going to `additem` it, but just make sure you are up to the stage `Find King Olaf's Verse` otherwise simply gaining this item won't progress the quest.